# Content in RichHtmlField not rendered as HTML

Tags: 2010, development, html, richhtmlfield, markup

I have made a Content Type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Page (0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900888dea275b1a4513a29b0415dd95bfe2"
               Name="LandingPageV4"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description=""
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{6EC1D5A7-18B3-4F06-A2D0-BF1E84FE7045}" Name="Content1" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>

  <Field ID="{6EC1D5A7-18B3-4F06-A2D0-BF1E84FE7045}" Name="Content1" StaticName="Content1" DisplayName="Content1" Type="HTML" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" />
</Elements>
```

and placed a RichHtmlField control within my Page Layout:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="6ec1d5a7-18b3-4f06-a2d0-bf1e84fe7045" runat="server" id="RichHtmlField1">
</PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
```

But when I go to page properties and write something like `<div>a<b>s</b>d</div>`, it's not rendered as HTML when I'm on the page but it only writes the code inline on the page. Also when I go to Edit Page and try to insert a picture within this field it looks OK, but when I save the page it only displays inline HTML code like: `<img alt="content1.png" src="/AnalyticsReports/content1.png" style="margin: 5px"/><span id="ms-rterangecursor-start"></span><span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span>`

Help me, please. I've tried following this page http://www.rkinteractive.com/blogs/SoftwareDevelopment/post/2012/01/06/Creating-Custom-Content-Types-and-Page-Layouts-in-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx but it doesn't change a thing.
What can be the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a Content Type caching issue... Apparently SharePoint remembered the version of it when it was not fully developed.

Creating a new Site Collection resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="Content1" runat="server" id="RichHtmlField1">
</PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>`

I have replaced the name of the field as the value for the `FieldName` attribute

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Exception: `Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.RichHtmlField' does not have a public property named 'RichText'.`

Comment: PublishingWebControls seems to be not set to the right namespace, that causes this error.